# Python + CSV + xlsx + Pandas : Merging multiple CSV files into one multisheet CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, xlsx

I want to produce a multisheet CSV file from a multisheet xlsx file. For that I wrote this code:

```
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'Smallys ORDER.xlsx', on_demand=True)
df_list = []

names = xls.sheet_names()
names.remove('EVENT')

for name in names:
    prod = pd.read_excel('Smallys ORDER.xlsx', name, index_col=None)
    prod.to_csv(name + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False) 
    df_list.append(prod)

df_final = pd.DataFrame()  

for df in df_list:
    df_final.append(df)

df_final.to_csv('smallys.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

It successfully converts the individual xlsx sheets to csv files. But cannot produce the multisheet csv.

this `print(df_final)` outputs this :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html mentions that the append method returns a new object. So it has to be stored into a variable. Since you are not storing, your df_final is always empty.
Try adding `df_final = df_final.append(df)`

Comment: It combines all the csv's into one csv file, one sheet. No multi-sheet csv produced.

Comment: @Debbie What exactly are you trying to achieve by a "multisheet" csv? The original "Smallys ORDER.xlsx" file is multisheet because of attributes special to .xlsx files. A .csv is simply a file full of data delimited by commas and has no support for multisheet.